# Rolling MySQL function to provide max value up to each row in an ordered column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to grab the max value in a column up to and including the current row. In the xample below, I've ordered the table by date. I would like to calculate the value of rollingMaxSource as shown. Starting from the top, it reports the max value found up to that point. I then compare the max value to the source value. If source is lower than max, I flag it, since with this ordering the value of source should only be equal to or higher than the previous row.

Can this be done in MySQL?

| Account | Source | rollingMaxSource | flag | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10 | false | 2022-05-01 |
| 1 | 10 | 10 | false | 2022-06-01 |
| 1 | 9 | 10 | true | 2022-07-01 |
| 1 | 10 | 10 | false | 2022-08-01 |
| 1 | 11 | 11 | false | 2022-09-01 |

Comment: Please add another table with your expected result.

Comment: are you want to get flag value? i dont really understand cause you don't provide your table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with windowing functions, which requires MySQL 8.0:

```
SELECT Account, Source, rollingMaxSource,
  Source < rollingMaxSource AS flag,
  date
FROM (
  SELECT Account, Source, date,
    MAX(Source) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS rollingMaxSource
  FROM mytable
) AS t;
```

This works when MAX() is used as a window function because the default frame includes from the earliest row to the current row.

Comment: Please don't ask how to do this if the version of MySQL is older than 8.0. You must upgrade to 8.0 if you need this feature.